# Set minimum year (use to select DOB) for Datepicker dialog

Tags: android, calendar, datepickerdialog

I have create a function for my code which set a rule to restrict user to select the day earlier then systems date from date picker dialog

```
protected void setMinMax() {
    Calendar minAllowedDate = CommUtils.getMinAllowedDate();
    minAllowedDate.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1000);
      datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minAllowedDate.getTimeInMillis());
```

now i want to create another date picker for user to select DOB, what i want to do is to set a rules that user DOB should be on age 4-150 which means the YEAR that user can select should be -4 & -150 from systems date. If using the the code above, what should i put in

```
minAllowedDate.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1000);
```

i had tried with below code which give me the year 150 as min option

```
minAllowedDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, -150);
```

Comment: I probably would not use the `Calendar` class, it is long outdated and poorly designed, and today we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. That said, `minAllowedDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, -150);` is correct.

Comment: [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? Also asking because creating one may help yourself understanding the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that most of the solution using the method .add(Calendar.YEAR,-4), however this also create limit to the month & date to be select. For example, When the current date is 11/Jun/2018, running that line of code you can have 4 years before(2018-4=2014) but also limit in your month + day which you can only select date before 11/Jun/2018.

After several tried, i had came out the solution which manually set the day & month to 31/Dec so that i can have an option range from 31/12/2014 to 1/1/2014

```
    Calendar calStart = new GregorianCalendar();
    calStart.setTime(new Date());
    calStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    calStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    calStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, -150);

    Calendar calEnd = new GregorianCalendar();
    calEnd.setTime(new Date());
    calEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    calEnd.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
    calEnd.add(Calendar.YEAR,-4);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calStart.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calEnd.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below for minimum and maximum

```
Calendar calStart = new GregorianCalendar();
calStart.setTime(new Date());
calStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, -150);

Calendar calEnd = new GregorianCalendar();
calEnd.setTime(new Date());
calEnd.add(Calendar.YEAR, -4);
```

Comment: for the End date -4, it also set the limit for the month, e.g you can only select the date before 7-jun-2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:startYear` which will include the start year.

Look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android:startYear).